# What are the issue if LookUp is used after Merge Join in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am creating a package in which I am using two transformation Merge Join and Look Up. Look Up is immediate successor to Merge Join (means using Look Up just after Merge Join). While executing my package, it got stuck and speed of input consumption in look Up is very slow and taking too much time. package still running.

Kindly find the attached screenshot.

[image]

Merge join - Using left outer join

Look Up -  Using No cache

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: What's the query behind the look up component? Also, If you are using 'table/view' I suggest you use SQL statement instead because that is much faster. (Also applies for your sources)

Comment: I avoid using lookup altogether. Why not use another merge join?

Answer (score 0):

Your lookup has 468 rows being sent to it and it is performing "whatever" you have defined as your source for *each* row being sent.

My guess is that you have blocking in the lookup table/query and that is why no information has been passed on to the output buffers from the lookup. On the database where the lookup is pointed to, try something like `sp_who2` or `sp_whoisactive` (go download and install) and you'll likely see that your source query is blocked by some other process.

There is nothing intrinsically different about a lookup after a merge join as opposed to any other preceding component.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using both the sources as OLEDB, you can avoid merge join transformation by trying to achieve the same using TSQL joins.